# getIntExtra() always returning the default value

Tags: java, android, android-intent, int

I have two different apps, AppA and AppB, I am trying to send an int from AppB to AppA, but the getIntExtra() in AppA is always getting the default value 0. 
Currently in AppA, gameRecords_str is receiving the correct string value, but I keep getting the default value 0 for gameCounter. What went wrong?

AppB:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM gameRecord";
Cursor mcursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
int counter = mcursor.getCount();   // Find out the number of records found in database
System.out.println("Number of record : " + counter);

Intent sendCounter = new Intent();
sendCounter.setAction("com.joy.AppA.LAUNCH_IT");
sendCounter.putExtra("counter", counter);
startActivity(sendCounter);

String gameRecord_str;
int flag;

mcursor.moveToFirst();
if (mcursor != null) {
  if (mcursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {

         String record = mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex("record"));
         gameRecord_str = record;

         Intent i = new Intent();
         i.setAction("com.joy.AppA.LAUNCH_IT");
         i.putExtra("gameRecord", gameRecord_str);
         startActivity(i);

         } while (mcursor.moveToNext());
```

AppA:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int gameCounter = intent.getIntExtra("counter", 0); //Number of records from game AppB
System.out.println("gameCounter : " + gameCounter);

for (int i=0; i<=gameCounter; i++) {
String gameRecords_str = intent.getStringExtra("gameRecord");
System.out.println("Game record received from AppB : " + gameRecords_str);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: update your manifest, https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: @HamidGoodarzi, I'm sorry but what do you mean? Currently the gameRecords_str is receiving correctly, only the gameCounter integer is getting default value 0.

Comment: Why do you start twice the same activity with different parameters? Of course the first instance only gets 'counter' and the second one only 'gameRecord'.

Comment: @greenapps Cause I wanted to send the gameCounter value over first before sending gameRecord. So you mean I don't have to create another new intent "i" to send the gameRecord? I can use the same intent "sendCounter" to send the gameRecord?

Comment: @unintendedjoy yes you can use same intent for both purpose.

Comment: You can putExtra as many parameters as you want.